sum of inradii of a orthodiagonal quadrilateral inscribed in a square
Consider a quadrilateral with perpendicular diagonals inscribed in a square such that exactly one vertex of the quadrilateral lies on each side of the square. The sides and diagonals of the quadrilateral divide the square into eight triangles. Each of these triangles is colored with one of two available colors in such a way that any two triangles sharing a side have different colors, as illustrated in the figure.
Prove that the sums of the inradii of the triangles of each color are equal.
My idea: Use areas with $$[ABC] = \frac{a+b+c}{2}(r) = sr = \frac{ab}{2}$$ since all triangles are perpendicular. Then each square with white and black is cycle and thus all of them have the same angles. But I cannot see anything else that allows me to get the angles or sides in correlation.
I would be really grateful for any hints or the solution.
Thank you very much in advance.

Carnot's inradius-circumradius Theorem seems relevant, especially since each triangle of one color shares a circumcircle with a triangle of the other.

Blue's approach works. It remains to show that the lengths along the perimeter of the square are sum up accordingly (to half the perimeter). Work if out from here, if you're stuck, state what you've tried or shown.

@LarryDoc Can you please tell us whether the contest, to which your question belongs, is still active or not? Answerers are not supposed to give hints or answer problems while the contest is active.

At first thank you Blue and Calvin Lin, I was able to solve it, thank you very much.
And @YNK, of course, sorry. It is from the Mathematical Olympiad from Germany from 2017, 3rd round: https://www.mathematik-olympiaden.de/moev/index.php?option=com_download&thema=a&datei=A57123b.pdf&format=raw

@LarryDoc Thanks for replying to the question I raised in my earlier comment. Happy to read that you were able to find a solution. I hope you don’t mind, if I upload my answer to your question for the benefit of those who visit your post.
